# MatSnackBar open does not pick the style from styles.css

Tags: angular

I have an angular service called UIService as below which can open a MatSnackBar. When it's called the color properties defined in the panelClass don't seem to be picked up.

UIService code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {ReplaySubject, Subject} from 'rxjs';
import {MatSnackBar} from '@angular/material';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UiServiceService {

  loadingChanged: Subject<boolean> = new ReplaySubject<boolean>();
  navigationChanged: Subject<string> = new ReplaySubject<string>();
  constructor(private  matSnackbar: MatSnackBar) {}

  openSnackBar(message: string) {
    this.matSnackbar.open(message, null, {
      duration: 3000,
      verticalPosition: 'top',
      panelClass: ['warning']
    });
  }
}
```

Styles.css looks as below

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
html, body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

::ng-deep .warning{
  background: #2196F3;
}
```

I have included below in angular.json as well

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
```

In my index.html, I included below in the head section

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./src/styles.css">
```

Yet the snack bar does not appear with the correct color.
Have I missed any thing. Kindly help
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular, component level styles only apply to that components html. `::ng-deep` is used when you also want those styles to apply to children of the component. Since you are declaring the style globally there is no need to use `::ng-deep`, `.warning` should suffice.

See the Angular [docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)